# Phonegap build sms implementation don't work

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm trying to devellop an application to send sms compiled with phonegap build.
I have declared the [sms plugin][1] in my config.xml but when I try my app nothing is done. I'm using jquery mobile.

Here is my code

```
//code page accueil
$( document ).on( "pagecreate", "#accueil", function( event ) {
//alert( "pageAccueil was just enhanced by jQuery Mobile!" );
$( document ).on( "click", "#envoyerSms", function( event ) {
 alert("le click envoyerSms fonctionne");

      var number = $('#numberTxt').val();
    var msg = $('#messageTxt').val();
    alert(number);
    alert(msg);

    //CONFIGURATION
    var options = {
        replaceLineBreaks: false, // true to replace \n by a new line, false by default
        android: {
            intent: 'INTENT'  // send SMS with the native android SMS messaging
            //intent: '' // send SMS without open any other app
        }
    };

    var success = function () { alert('Message sent successfully'); };
    var error = function (e) { alert('Message Failed:' + e); };
    sms.send(number, message, options, success, error);




    });
});//accueil
```

Is someone can help me please ?

Comment: Try declare '<access origin="sms:*" launch-external="yes" />' in your _config.xml_ file. From [source](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html)

Comment: Same result with when I modify my config.xml file. Any other idea ? It seems that my code is correct. I see the 3 alert() correctly but no sms is sent.

Comment: Is 'alert('Message sent successfully');' called?? If this alert called, I have no idea :( , you could try to build application by Intel XDK, it's same with phonegap.

Comment: No the alert message 'Message sent successfully' is not called

Comment: You're a Paid Plan of [phonegap](https://build.phonegap.com/)? You could try Intel XDK to build your application more easily than phonegap. I think that your code is OK. it should run normally.

Comment: Ok thank you I would try Intel XDK